# How to add only one row in inline Jqgrid

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I am working on one webapplication in that I am using Inline Jqgrid . but when web form is in create mode then in That jqgrid only one row will be added not more than one row .for that I will be try like this:

```
if(CardCode=="")
            {
                $("#Stages").jqGrid("inlineNav","#nav-Stages",{        
                    edit: false,
                    add: false,
                    addicon:"ui-icon-plus",
                    save:true,     
                    view:true,     
                    cancel: false,
                    addParams:{position:'last'}
                }); 
                  $("#Stages").jqGrid('addRow',{position:'last'}); 
            }
```

In that jqgrid add,edit properties are set to false and single row is added at last position.but in this situation the issue is that I am not able validate that jqgrid because save button is inactive at that time then what is solution for that .
I am using jqgrid version 5.0.0
Please suggest some solution.

Comment: Try to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) 4.13.5 instead of commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which you use currently. You can just load jqGrid files directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs)). Free jqGrid is the fork of jqGrid, which I develop. It uses internal events in many places. Thus Save button of `inlineNav` or `formatter: "actions"` will be **automatically active** after calling of `addRow`, which starts inline editing.

Comment: Yes it Works.Thank you so much @Oleg.

Comment: You are welcome! I posted the same information as the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use [free jqGrid](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid) (the latest released version is 4.13.5) instead of commercial [Guriddo jqGrid JS](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334), which you use currently. You can just load jqGrid files directly from CDN (see [the wiki article](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/wiki/Access-free-jqGrid-from-different-CDNs) and [the come example](https://free-jqgrid.github.io/getting-started/index.html#type_of_data_code)).

Free jqGrid is the fork of jqGrid, which I develop. It uses internal events in many places. Thus Save button of `inlineNav` (or `formatter: "actions"` or in any other way) will be **automatically active** on starting inline editing. Thus you should have activated Save button after calling of `addRow` method, which starts inline editing.